# Need to translate in function iteration from Python to Julia

Tags: python, julia

I've got this sentence in Python:

```
max(xrange(j, n), key=lambda i: abs(m[i][j]))
```

I know how to implement lambda sentence but don't have any idea how to do the `xrange(j, n)` iteration.

Best regards, 
Szymon

Comment: It can be translated to `maximum(abs(m[x][j]) for  x in j:n-1)`. I'd assume it can be done in several ways.

Comment: And welcome to upvote privileges btw :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a range similar to matlab, with the colon operator. For example

```
1:5 # prints range 1 : 5
```

However, your code would translate to
   `maximum(map(abs, m))`